# iOS CoreImage Instant photo effect in Android, how to make it?

Tags: java, android, photokit

I'm a newbie with Android and I would like to filter an image with Instant photo effect on Android, like the CIPhotoEffectInstant that's available for iOS: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIPhotoEffectInstant

I've found many tutorials about grayscaling, gamma correction, sepia, etc, but nothing about the most used photo filter, Instant. 
Any idea about how to build it in .java?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can learn to apply the filter by learning how it been done in some android photo library.

Take a look from a library, [PhotoFiltersSDK](https://github.com/Zomato/AndroidPhotoFilters):

> PhotoFiltersSDK aims to provide fast, powerful and flexible image processing instrument for creating awesome effects on any image media.